# EXTPROC issue during 10g to 11g database

Tags: migration, oracle-11g, oracle-10g, plsql, process

I am currently 10g  to 11g database migration and trying to configure EXTPROC.
EXTPROC32 was configured as part of 10g to execute C++ library and working fine.

It appears that 11g does not provided EXTPROC32 so C++ library compiled for 64 bit and configured as follows.

Listener configuration and confirmed file is available in */opt/UTILfddb/lib/utillib.so.* in database server.

```
LISTENEREXTPROC =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = extproc))
  )
SID_LIST_LISTENEREXTPROC =
  (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=/opt/UTILfddb/lib/utillib.so,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/ucblib/sparcv9:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
  (SID_NAME = extproc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db)
  )
  )
```

Following errors returned when try to execute pl/sql function:

```
SQL> select gmt_sysdate from dual;
select gmt_sysdate from dual
  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06520: PL/SQL: Error loading external library
ORA-06522: ld.so.1: extproc: fatal: /opt/UTILfddb/lib/utillib.so: open failed:
No such file or directory
ORA-06512: at "UTIL.GMT_SYSDATE", line 4
```

Do I need to grant any permission to oracle user to execute or load this file?
Can you please help to resolve this issue? Let me know if you need any further information. Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
(ora11)% file utillib.so
utillib.so:    ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped

ora11:%file lsnrctl
lsnrctl:        ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped

[oracle@rms-ora11:]%ldd utillib.so
libc.so.1 => /lib/64/libc.so.1
libm.so.2 => /lib/64/libm.so.2
/lib/sparcv9/../libm/sparcv9/libm_hwcap1.so.2
/platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
```

Comment: You're on Solaris, yeah? Have you definitely compiled it for the correct architecture? Run `file /opt/UTILfddb/lib/utillib.so` and `file $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle` and make sure the architectures are the same. Also, Solaris uses `SHLIB_PATH`, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Another thing to check is `ldd /opt/UTILfddb/lib/utillib.so` to check that all of the libraries dependencies are available

Comment: Thanks, Details updated  and according to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/listener.htm LD_LIBRARY_PATH path configured